# Should i use Adobe Flash or Flex for action scripting

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I am new to flash and learning action script 3.
I am using flex. But i find it hard.

Should i use Adobe flash so that i can insert the components by drag and drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Design view in Flex to drag and drop components too,
but that doesn't matter.

What matters is is why you want learn actionscript 3 ? What do you want to use if for ?

For RIAs and the like, Flex is a good option. For rich media websites/presentations/games, go
with Flash as you'll have more/easier control over media.

Bad news is since actionscript 3, there is no easy way, but all the hard work will pay off.
Once you get used to it/get to the point where it clicks, it might be a bit hard, but not impossible.

Goodluck